# Somar linha anterior no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aplicação-web

Possuo uma linha de lançamento, no qual essa linha precisaria receber o valor da linha anterior +1, algum exemplo de como fazer isso?

Estrutura da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `lancamento` ( 
`data` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
`descricao` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
`debito` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL, 
`credito` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL, 
`saldo` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL, 
`lancamento` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: Precisa fazer isso antes de inserir o registro?

Comment: Tem que ser tudo no SQL ? De onde vem os dados do lançamento ?

Comment: Sim, no caso faria poderia fazer algo como um SELECT pegando o valor da linha anterior e depois somando ele com 1 recebendo o valor da linha seguinte, o problema seria o SELECT no qual deveria selecionar a linha anterior.

Comment: estou fazendo com php e mysql, o lançamento iria começar em 1 e cada execução geraria um lançamento, esse lançamento é apenas um identificador para controle e também futuras alterações.

Comment: Se você apenas deixar o campo como `AUTO INCREMENTO` não resolve? Ou você já tem outro campo `AUTO INCREMENTO`?

Comment: Resolve, como poderia faze-lo?

Comment: Coloca a estrutura da sua tabela na pergunta para que eu possa te ajudar melhor. Para conseguir a estrutura, basta executar o comando `SHOW CREATE TABLE nome_da_tabela`.

Comment: `lancamento`SELECT * FROM `caixa` WHERE 1

Comment: @Wel Execute este comando `SHOW CREATE TABLE nome_da_tabela` e coloque aqui o resultado

Comment: Não estou entendendo muito bem, você quer ver o output certo? é algo como isso

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66590/discussion-between-roberto-fagundes-and-wel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `MySQL` já tem uma opção nativa com este objetivo, basta informar que ele deve utilizar o `AUTO INCREMENTO` na hora de criar a tabela, como não foi feito essa opção também pode ser informada através de um `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE `lancamento`   
  CHANGE `lancamento` `lancamento` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  FIRST,
  CHANGE `data` `data` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL  AFTER `lancamento`, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`lancamento`);
```

A partir de agora, não precisa informar o campo `lancamento` na hora de dar o `INSERT` e automaticamente o `MySQL` irá gerar um número incrementado:

```
INSERT INTO `lancamento` (`data`, `descricao`, `debito`, `credito`, `saldo`)
VALUES ('', '', 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Funcionou como precisava, muito obrigado pela paciência, ainda sou péssimo com banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Eu imagino que você terá de consultar previamente o valor que deseja somar 1 e salvar em uma variável, fazendo um `select` pata pegar o valor.

```
Lock tables TABELA write;

$VALORSALVO = SELECT VALORATUAL FROM TABELA ;
```

Pegando o valor que você deseja, você deve utilizar a variável que recebeu somando 1 na mesma, fazendo um insert comum.

```
INSERT INTO TABELA( ID, VALORNOVO, )
VALUES ( 3 , $VALORSALVO+1);

unlock tables;
```

Repare que travei a tabela ( `Lock tables TABELA write` ), durante a operação para garantir que consigamos fazer a logica proposta e por fim destravei ( `unlock tables;` ) .

Comment: No caso isso selecionaria a ultima tabela inserida?

Comment: Não, você tem que informa a tabela no select e no insert, no seu select você vai buscar o que quer somar 1 e no insert somar 1 a ele

Comment: Esse é o problema, não consigo pensar em uma forma de buscar a última linha de forma automática, como poderia seleciona-la para fazer essa adição? visto que o identificador é o que eu quero somar. Acredito que se tivesse uma forma de fazer um SELECT apenas com o maior lançamento resolveria meu problema.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso na trigger de insert, este mesmo codigo